# sort a sequence but sort some particular elements in another order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose I want to sort a sequence of names in alphabetical order, but with one additional rule:

if any name in the following list:

`Mike Cathy James Albert Austin`

appears, they shall be moved to the **head** of the sequence and be sorted as `Mike -> Cathy -> James -> Albert -> Austin`.

For example, if the original sequence is like this:

```
Conan,Cary,Clarence,Cathy,Mike,Blake,Baron,Vaughan,Albert,Gabriel,Cathy
```

the desired outcome is:

**Mike,Cathy,Cathy,Albert,** Baron,Blake,Cary,Clarence,Conan,Gabriel,Vaughan

Note `Mike, Cathy and Albert` are no longer sorted in alphabetical order, they as a whole precede other common names and have their own predefined order.

---

And some further explanations for my question:

1. The original sequence is retrieved in non-trivial way (for example from a database), so it is preferred to retrieve the whole sequence at one time and sort it in memory.
2. It is not guaranteed that how many of these particular names appears in the original sequence, nor how many times they appears.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this in a fast/efficient way?

Comment: You said the names should retain their order in the list, so shouldn't your desired output start with `Cathy Mike Albert Cathy`?

Comment: @IVlad, sorry for the obscurity. I mean the special names retain their order of "Mike Cathy James Albert Austin", and they as a whole shall precede other non-special names.

Comment: "and *retain* their order *as*" - it's either retain OR as. please clarify.

Comment: I agree with Will Ness answer. You can even write the part where you take aside the particular names as the first step of a quicksort algorithm which may save you some computation time if the array is very large and the particular names are not to frequent. Roughly speaking your algorithm would do : take a pivot at random (not within the particular names) partition the initial array in three : A that contains the particular name, B that contain the elements before the pivot, C that contains the elements after it. Sort A, B and C and return A append B append C

Comment: Or you could simply write this into the comparison operator, and do a regular run-of-the-mill sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach:

1. Split the list of names (or filter, depending on your language) into two lists based on membership in the special sort bucket or not;
2. Sort the special names list based on your desired order;
3. Sort the second list lexicographically;
4. Combine the lists.

That method should apply to any language with a sort and a list or array to hold the names.

In Python:

```
names=['Conan', 'Cary', 'Clarence', 'Cathy', 'Mike', 'Blake', 'Baron', 'Vaughan', 'Albert', 'Gabriel', 'Cathy']

specials=['Mike', 'Cathy', 'James', 'Albert', 'Austin']
# split the lists. 
n1=[n for n in names if n in specials]  # ifilter would also work in Python
n2=[n for n in names if n not in specials]

# sort the first list based on order of specials, second lexicographically and combine:
print sorted(n1, key=lambda n:specials.index(n))+sorted(n2)
```

Prints:

```
['Mike', 'Cathy', 'Cathy', 'Albert', 'Baron', 'Blake', 'Cary', 'Clarence', 'Conan', 'Gabriel', 'Vaughan']
```

---

An improvement is to:

1. Create a two element data element comprised of negated integer for the index into the list / array of specials as the first element and the name as the second element;
2. Sort the list / array based on either a key or custom `cmp` function based on that element.

In Python, you would use a tuple in a key function. In C, you would write a custom cmp function. With that, you can sort `names` in place depending on the features of your language.

The two elements in the tuples would be the negated index of the name in specials (adjusted for zero based indexes) then the name. The first element of the tuple will trump the second element if non-zero. Since the first element is an integer, it will sort properly even if there are more than 10 names in `specials`.

Again, in Python:

```
def cf(n):
    rtr=(specials.index(n)-len(specials)-1 if n in specials else 0, n)
    print rtr   # to show what is being generated for the sort key...
    return rtr

names.sort(key=cf)   # sorts inplace
```

Prints:

```
(0, 'Conan')
(0, 'Cary')
(0, 'Clarence')
(-5, 'Cathy')
(-6, 'Mike')
(0, 'Blake')
(0, 'Baron')
(0, 'Vaughan')
(-3, 'Albert')
(0, 'Gabriel')
(-5, 'Cathy')
```

Now `names` has been sorted inplace and in one pass to:

```
['Mike', 'Cathy', 'Cathy', 'Albert', 'Baron', 'Blake', 'Cary', 'Clarence', 'Conan', 'Gabriel', 'Vaughan']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like the negative index idiom, very clever.

Comment: The same multi element tupple approach works for multiple sort keys. It the the method used to collate Unicode into language correct collation order for example. You can have as many integer prefixes as sort keys that you wish to consider. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One trick, for almost any soft of sorting-with-special-cases, is to transform your elements into "keys" that will sort the way you want, do a regular sort, and then transform them back.

For example,

1. Turn regular names like "Gabriel" into "1.Gabriel"
2. Turn special names like "Cathy" into "0.1.Cathy" and "Mike" into "0.0.Mike".
3. Sort normally.  The leading zeros will force the special names before the regular names.  Within the special names, the next digit will give the desired sort order.  Within the regular names, sorting will be lexicographic.
4. Undo the transformations.  Since the original transform merely added information, you can always transform back.

Some languages or libraries (like C or C++) have a way to override the comparison.  That's helpful (and efficient) only for simple cases.  Other languages, (like maybe Python), have a way to provide the sorting keys on demand, which would make this approach quite simple.

If I recall, Knuth has an example of this approach in *TAoCP*.  In that one, he has book titles, with sorting rules like being case blind, moving 'A' and 'the" to the ends of the title, etc.

Comment: Otherwise known as a decorated sort or [Schwartzian Transform](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html) In you example, however, the 'decoration' needs to sort properly as integers. In asciibetical, 19 sorts less than 2

Comment: @MooingDuck:  I thought I said that.

Comment: Colt45:  I believe my decoration scheme properly takes that into account.  All the of `'0'` sort before the `'1'` in ASCII.    There were fewer than 10 special names, so I used a single ASCII digit for those.

Comment: Given that you also append a ascii representation of an int to the front of regular names, "1.Gabriel" for example, you are limited to 10 special and 10 regular name, no?

Comment: @Colt45:  Yes, it was an example to solve this specific problem, which has fewer than 10 special names.  I figured it was obvious that if the parameters of the problem were different that you would have to design a key transformation that does what you want lexicographically.

Comment: Colt45:  No, you're not limited to 10 regular names.  "1.anything" is always greater than "0.anything".  The first character merely partitions in to "special" and "regular".

Comment: But you would need to use '9.anything' then you could use '0.special' .. '8.special' and you are limited to 9 special sort names, no?

Comment: @Colt45:  Please re-read my answer carefully, noting that I had two digits for the special names, the leading 0 indicates it's a special name and should come before anything else.  The special names then have another digit that gives the relative sort order within the special names.

Answer (score 0):

So my algorithm would be the following, in pseudo-code.

Input : a vector V of strings, a liste L of strings (the exceptional cases), an order associated to L

```
Let pivot be a random element of V
Let A,B,C be three empty arrays of strings
For name in V
    if (name in L)
        add name to A 
    else if (name <= pivot)   // for the lexicographic order
        add name to B
    else if (name > pivot)    // for the lexicographic order
        add name to C
If (pivot in L)
    add pivot to A
Else
    add pivot to B
Sort A for the order associated with L
Sort B for the lexicographic order
Sort C for the lexicographic order
Merge B in A
Merge C in A
Return A
```